# Picasa doesn't display any new picture

Tags: picasa

Usually, any new picture that's imported to my computer is added automatically to Picasa. Since a few days ago, any new picture imported to my computer doesn't appear anywhere in Picasa. I have tried reinstalling picasa but it didn't work. When asked whether to delete the DB when uninstalling Picasa, I said "no" because I don't want to lose the recognized faces I've tagged.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's 2021 and I experienced the same challenge. Just to discover that Picasa doesn't recognise the photo files that I labelled starting with either a full stop (.) or an underscore (_). When I renamed the files, Picasa automatically imported it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Picasa application
2. Go to file -> open -> import first time your relevant folder of photos.
3. First you added all the photos it should be always there in Picasa.

Comment: The relevant folders are already marked with a green V indicating they're added to Picasa, but the pictures still do not appear if they're newer than a few days ago.

Comment: right click on photo make default to picasa.

Comment: By the green V I think you mean the green tick. This shows that the folders are scanned once only when you first add them to Picasa. Go to "Tools" - "Folder Manager" and then select "Scan Always" for the folders you want constantly updated.